# What does justify the difference between my local code and my branches differences?

Tags: git, merge, version-control, bitbucket

I had a strange situation today and I still can't understand the reason why git had this behavior.

I had a `branch A` that I `merged` with `master`.

During the `merge` `branch A` got `deleted`:

```
git merge --no-ff branch A
git branch -D branch A
```

I `reverted` `master` to its state before `branch A merge` and recreated `branch A` under the name `branch B` and reset it to its last commit:

```
git revert merge_commit_id -m 1
git checkout -b branch B
git reset --hard branch_A_commit_id
```

Now with that steps I had on my local:

- `master` as it was before everything and when I tested on my local environment everything was as before.
- `branch B` had the changes as `branch A` was before everything, when testing on my local environment it was as before however nothing was different from `master` for Git.

I added some changes in `branch B` and pushed them to the distant repository and only the newly added changes differed from `master`, even though everything was different on my local environment (I had all changes from `branch A` and `branch B`).

So I had all my changes locally in `branch B`, I could not see them in `git status`, nor commit or push them since Git behaves as if they weren't different from `master`, both my distant and local branches were synchronized and up to date.

Doing `git pull origin branch B` didn't change my code in local. Pushing wouldn't do anything either.

I got my changes back by a workaround, but I would like to understand what happened here for Git and what would be the best way to get my old `branch A` back if such a situation happens again?

My best guess is that originally `branch A` got deleted during the merge so the commit I used to reset my `branch B` was actually referring to an old version of `master` which could explain the behavior since Git would assume my changes are an old version of `master` and not actual changes from `branch A`.

Comment: I don't use Bitbucket, and think it might help if you showed how this Bitbucket merge process goes. I assume you use a web interface to accomplish the merge.  (If so, note that you're doing the merge in *their* repository, not your own clone.)

Comment: It is indeed realised through bitbucket interface here which is doing the following `git merge branch A` `git branch -d branch A`.  I believe the issue doesn't come from this process though but from the "recovery" of `branch A`

Comment: There are a still a lot of unknowns here. Did bitbucket actually make a merge commit (one with two parents), or did it do a fast-forward or squash operation instead? What commands did you run on your own Git repository subsequent to the merge? Did you run `git revert -m` as required by a merge commit, or `git revert` as required by a non-merge commit?

Comment: I went to look for it: Bitbucket did a merge commit (basically `git merge --no-ff` ). The revert was `git revert -m`.

Comment: OK, let me see if that's sufficient to construct the sequence of events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, there are two Git repositories involved.  One Git repository is on Bitbucket, and one is on your local machine (`git clone url-of-bitbucket-repo` produces a second Git repository).  The two repositories will share *commits*, as identified by commit hash IDs, but each Git repository has *its own set of branch names*.  What you'll see in branches therefore depends on *which repository you look at*.

#### Basics

Before we get to the process, or "what happened", let's start with these bullet point items (many of which may be familiar to you—if they are, feel free to skip forward to the next section):

- Commits are actually identified by their unique hash IDs.  While every commit gets its own unique hash ID, different from every other commit, every Git also *computes* the hash ID the same way.  So every separate Git repository uses the *same* hash IDs for the same commits.  This means two Gits can easily tell whether they have each other's commits by comparing hash IDs.

  (To make this work, no part of any commit can ever be changed once it's made.  The hash ID is based on all of the data-and-metadata *in* the commit, and if even one bit in one file, or one letter in the log message, were to change, that would invalidate the hash ID.  If you try to change a commit, what you end up doing is making a *new* commit with a new and different hash ID.  The old commit still exists!)
- Each commit stores a full snapshot of all files.  You can only view a snapshot as "changes to some files" by *comparing* that snapshot to some other snapshot.
- Each commit also stores some *metadata:* the name and email address of the commit's author, and a date-and-time stamp, for instance.  (There are actually two of these, one for "author" and one for "committer".)  Your commit log message is part of this as well.
- Each commit also stores the hash ID(s) of its immediate predecessor commits, which Git calls the *parents* of that commit.  (This is also part of the metadata.)
- Branch names just hold the hash ID of one single commit.  That commit is the one that should be treated as the *last* commit in the branch.
- In general, to make a new commit, you—or Git—come up with a new snapshot of files, write out that snapshot, add the appropriate metadata, and create a new commit.  This does not affect any existing commits in any way: the new commit gets a new, unique hash ID.  The new commit's *parent* commit(s) must be the hash IDs of some existing, valid commits in this repository.

  Since a branch name is the *last* commit in the branch, adding a new commit has Git update the current branch name—the branch you checked out with `git checkout`—so that it now identifies the new commit.  The new commit's parent is the commit you had checked out just a moment ago.

  This all works because the new commit refers back to the existing commit, which refers back to its parent, and so on.  We *add* commits to the branch by making sure the new commit remembers its parent.  If the new commit didn't remember its parent, and we were to set the branch name to remember the new commit, the previous commit would become, at best, very hard to find, because hash IDs are so random-looking.
- When you have two repositories, the commits get shared via `git fetch` and `git push`.  Note that `git pull` runs `git fetch` followed by a second Git command, usually `git merge`, on the theory that if you've just obtained some new commits from *their* Git, you probably want to integrate those commits into *your* branch name(s) somehow.  Your branch names remain yours, and `git fetch` itself does not touch them at all.  It's the *second* command that touches one of them.
- In order for your Git to remember the hash IDs that *their* Git calls "the last commit in the branch", the `git fetch` step first obtains any new commits from some other repository, then creates or updates your *remote-tracking names* for that repository.  If your Git is calling their Git `origin`, for instance, and they have a branch `master`, your Git will use your `origin/master` to remember what *their* Git says their `master` is.

  In other words, a fetch ends by setting *your* Git's *remote-tracking* names: your `origin/master` might change, for instance, but your own `master` *never* changes.  Your `origin/branch-A` might be created, or changed, or even *deleted*, but *your* `branch-A` *never* changes.
- Besides the direction of transfer, `git push` is very different from `git fetch` in one very important way.  At the end of `git push`, *your* Git requests, or even commands (`git push --force`), that *their* Git should set one of their **branch** names.  You don't have them set their remote-tracking names!  They may not even have remote-tracking names: it's relatively uncommon for server-side bare repositories to have them.

#### Drawing commit graph fragments and doing a merge

As we noted above, each commit stores the hash ID(s) of its immediate predecessors.  We, or Git, can use this to group our commits into a graph.  (This is more specifically a **D**irected **A**cyclic **G**raph or DAG, though we won't go into any more detail here.)  We find the *last* commit's hash ID—let's call it `H`—by reading a *branch name* like `master`.  The name contains the hash ID, so we say that `master` *points to* commit `H`:

```
              H   <-- master
```

But `H` itself contains a commit ID too: the hash ID of `H`'s parent.  Let's call that `G`.  `H` then points to `G`.  Of course `G` also points to something:

```
        <-G <-H   <-- master
```

Let's call the commit to which `G` points, `F`:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- master
```

This repeats all the way back to the very first commit, which—being the first commit—doesn't point anywhere.  Git calls this a *root commit*, and it's where, when following commits backwards like this, we have to stop.  (We usually stop earlier, when we get tired. :-) )

This backwards-pointing chain, built out of the commits, forms the commit graph.  It also means that we can define an "is an ancestor" test for any given pair of commits.  `G` is the parent of `H`, for instance, so `G` is an ancestor of `H`.  Meanwhile `F` is the parent of `G`, so `F` is also an ancestor of `H`.

Once we start adding *new* commits, though ... well, look at this partial graph drawing:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

Here, the name `branch1` identifies commit `J`, whose parent is `I`, whose parent is `H`.  So `H` is an ancestor of `J`.  The name `branch2` identifies commit `L`, whose parent is `K`, whose parent is `H`.  So `H` is also an ancestor of `L`.  But `I` is *not* an ancestor of `L`.  `I` is not a descendant of `L` either.

To achieve a merge, we pick one of these two branches—`git checkout branch1`, for instance—and then run merge on the other: `git merge branch2`.  Git will:

- find the best common ancestor (`H`), which Git calls the *merge base;*
- figure out what changed in `branch1` by comparing the merge base to the tip commit of `branch1`, i.e., `J`;
- figure out what changed in `branch2` by comparing the merge base to the tip of `branch2`, i.e., `L`; and
- *combine* the changes, applying the combined changes to the snapshot in `H`, to make a new merge commit `M`, that has *both* tip commits as its two parents.

This gives us:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

as our result.  (The name `branch1` is the one that got updated, because we checked it out.  To show that it's the branch we have checked out, I added `(HEAD)` to the branch label.)  Working backwards from a *merge* commit like `M` is a matter of going to *both* of its parents, so `git log` from `branch1` will show commit `M`, then all four commits `I`+`J` and `K`+`L` (in some order), and also commits `H` and earlier.

Note that in some cases, a merge can be done trivially:

```
...--G--H   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         \
          I--J   <-- branch2
```

Here, `git merge branch2` does not have to do a real merge.  The merge base commit `H` *is* the tip of `branch1`, and comparing `H` to `H` will always show no changes.  The result of combining nothing with something is always the "something", so the final result will always match commit `J`.  Git can be lazy and simply move the name `branch1` forward and check out commit `J`:

```
...--G--H
         \
          I--J   <-- branch1 (HEAD), branch2
```

Git calls this a *fast-forward merge*, even though there's no actual merging: it's really just a `git checkout` that drags the branch name along instead of switching to the other branch.

You can force a real merge, even in a fast-forward-y situation, using `git merge --no-ff`.  The result looks like this:

```
...--G--H------K   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          I--J   <-- branch2
```

where commit `K` is the new merge commit.

In all three cases, we *could* delete the name `branch2` safely afterward, because we can find whichever commit was the tip of `branch2` by looking at the tip of `branch1` and—if necessary—working backwards.

#### This is presumably what happened during your merge

Presumably Bitbucket's web interface for doing a merge is similar to GitHub's (I haven't used Bitbuckets).  You pick one branch, such as `master`, as the one that will "receive" the merge, then pick another branch, e.g., `branch-A`, as the one to merge.  Under the cover of the web page, Bitbucket does the equivalent of `git merge` or `git merge --no-ff`.  But then, as you said, Bitbucket also *deleted* the name `branch-A`.

Let's draw that:

```
          I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch-A
```

becomes:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L
```

or maybe:

```
          I--J   <-- branch-A
         /
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

becomes:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H------M   <-- master (HEAD)
```

#### Revert

A `git revert` works by adding a new commit that "undoes" whatever happened in the commit itself.  For both cherry-pick and revert, Git compares one commit to its parent (singular), to see what happened in that commit.  Then Git tries to re-do (cherry-pick) or un-do (revert) that change against the *current* commit.<sup>1</sup>  If that succeeds, Git makes a new one-parent commit.

For instance, consider a cherry-pick of commit `C`, while you have commit `H` checked out:

```
...--B--C--...   <-- other-branch
  \
   o--H   <-- current-branch (HEAD)
```

Git will compare the snapshots in `B` (parent) and `C` (child) to see what changed in `C`.  Applying those same changes to the snapshot in `H` gets us a new commit `I`:

```
...--B--C--...   <-- other-branch
  \
   o--H--I   <-- current-branch (HEAD)
```

The difference between the snapshots in `H` and `I` will be the same (except maybe for line numbers) as the difference between the snapshots in `B` and `C`.

A revert just tries to *un-apply* the changes, rather than copying the changes.  In both cases, if you're using a merge commit, it has *two* parents, so you must select one of the two using an extra `-m` argument to `git cherry-pick` or `git revert`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, Git actually does a full three-way merge here, using the selected commit's parent as the merge base, the current commit as the left side of the merge, and the selected commit as the right side of the merge.  The resulting commit is an ordinary commit rather than a merge commit, though, so it records only the current commit as the new commit's (single) parent.

---

#### Doing the revert

In this case, you did a revert, so let's draw it.  **But wait a second, you did the revert in your own repository, not in the one on Bitbucket!**  Let's draw *your* repository, after you run `git fetch` and `git merge`, or `git pull` to do both in one shot.

You start with:

```
          I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch-A
```

You now run `git fetch` and acquire commit `M`:

That's what you did in this case, so let's draw it:

```
          I--J   <-- master
         /    \
...--G--H      M    <-- origin/master
         \    /
          K--L   <-- branch-A
```

The fact that `branch-A` is gone **in the Git over at Bitbucket** does not affect *your* `branch-A`.  None of your branch names change!  At most, if you had an `origin/branch-A`, your `git fetch` would remove `origin/branch-A`.

If you delete your own `branch-A` now, that's *your* responsibility.  But let's say that you do, and that you also have your `master` fast-forward to point to commit `M`.  Perhaps you `git checkout master` and then `git pull` so as to gain `M`, update your `origin/master`, and then fast-forward your `master` all in one command, then you delete your own `branch-A` after seeing `origin/branch-A` go away:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M    <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
         \    /
          K--L
```

Now you run `git revert -m 1 <hash>`, so let's draw the graph.  We'll stop drawing `origin/master` (it still points to `M`):

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M--N   <-- master (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L
```

Here `N` un-does the changes brought in by the `K-L` chain (well, presumably—you could have undone the changes brought in by the `I-J` chain by using `git revert -m 2`).  In any case the name `master` now points to commit `N`.

#### Re-creating branch-A

Let's recap a bit:

> I reverted master to its state before branch A merge and recreated branch A under the name branch B and reset it to its last commit:
>
> ```
> git revert merge_commit_id -m 1
> git checkout -b branch B
> git reset --hard branch_A_commit_id
> ```

The graph up through commit `N` represents your state after the `git revert`.  The `git checkout -b branch-B` step just creates a new name, `branch-B`, pointing to the current commit (`N`), and attaches `HEAD` to that new name:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M--N   <-- master, branch-B (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L
```

Your `git reset --hard` resets the index and work-tree (which we're not drawing!) and moves the *name to which `HEAD` is attached*, i.e., `branch-B`, to the hash ID you supply.  Presumably that's the hash ID of commit `L`:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M--N   <-- master
         \    /
          K--L   <-- branch-B (HEAD)
```

> I added some changes in branch B and pushed them to the distant repository ...

Changing files in the work-tree, adding them to the index, and committing would get you a new commit:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M--N   <-- master
         \    /
          K--L--O   <-- branch-B (HEAD)
```

You could then `git push origin branch-B` (perhaps with `-u` as well) to send new commit `O` to the other Git, and get them to create *their* branch name `branch-B` pointing to new commit `O`.

> and only the newly added changes differed from master, even though everything was different on my local environnment (I had all changes from branch A and branch B).

Here's where things go off the rails: to view *changes*, you must compare commit `O` to something.  By itself, it's just a snapshot.  What are you comparing commit `O` to?

> Doing `git pull origin branch-B` didn't change my code in local ...

Running `git pull` first runs `git fetch`, then runs `git merge`.  In this case you'd have your Git call up their (Bitbucket's) Git and ask about their `branch-B`, which identifies commit `O`.  You already have commit `O`, so no commits come over.  Your Git then updates your `origin/branch-B` to point to commit `O`, if it didn't already—it probably did—and then you have your Git run `git merge <hash-of-O>`.

The current commit *is* commit `O`, so there's nothing to merge.  So it's not surprising that this does nothing.

#### Conclusion

The above might be somewhat wrong: perhaps the merge that Bitbucket made could have been a fast-forward merge (but clearly wasn't), in which case the graph drawing at the point where you have only `master` and have done `git revert -m 1` should be:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H------M--N   <-- master (HEAD)
```

and it's not at all clear to me which commit you used when you re-created the name `branch-A` (perhaps you had it point to commit `H`).  The rest, however, should be pretty much the same: you'd end up with:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H------M--N   <-- master
         \
          O   <-- branch-B
```

When you *view* commit `O`, you must do so in some sort of context.  The `git show` command views it by comparing it to its parent `H`.  A snapshot viewer would look at its saved snapshot.

In puzzling cases like this, it's always helpful to stop and draw the *graph*.  Be mindful of the fact that two different Git repositories can have different branch names ... and, if you have not run `git fetch` or `git push`, one repository might have some commit(s) that the other does not.  Once the commits are shared, though, so that every repository has every commit, it's all a matter of looking at the graph: find the tip commits from the branch names, and work backwards.

Comment: I analysed my situation and here is what I had: (referring to 3rd graph of _"Re-creating branch-A"_ )
- the differences between commit `O` and commit `N` were only the changes of commit `O`. This was both the case on my Git and on bitbucket's Git.
- my local changes were as the schema above suggests: commit `O` with commit `L` as a parent.

I believe I did something wrong in the process since the behavior isn't logical.
I accept your answer since it is really helpful to understand such situation.